# using generate-id() and keys to get rid of repetitions in XSLT

Tags: xslt, key

From the following xml data:

```
<lieferungen>
    <artikel id="1111">
    <name>apfel</name>
    <preis stueckpreis="true">8.97</preis>
    <lieferant>Fa. Krause</lieferant>
    </artikel>
    <artikel id="7866">
        <name>Kirschen</name>
        <preis stueckpreis="false">10.45</preis>
        <lieferant>Fa. Helbig</lieferant>
    </artikel>
    <artikel id="3526">
        <name>apfel</name>
        <preis stueckpreis="true">12.67</preis>
        <lieferant>Fa. Liebig</lieferant>
    </artikel>
    <artikel id="7866">
        <name>Kirschen</name>
        <preis stueckpreis="false">17.67</preis>
        <lieferant>Fa. Krause</lieferant>
    </artikel>
    <artikel id="3526">
        <name>apfel</name>
        <preis stueckpreis="true">9.54</preis>
        <lieferant>Fa. Mertes</lieferant>
    </artikel>
    <artikel id="7866">
        <name>Kirschen</name>
        <preis stueckpreis="false">16.45</preis>
        <lieferant>Fa. Hoeller</lieferant>
    </artikel>
    <artikel id="7868">
        <name>Kohl</name>
        <preis stueckpreis="false">3.20</preis>
        <lieferant>Fa. Hoeller</lieferant>
    </artikel>
    <artikel id="7866">
        <name>Kirschen</name>
        <preis stueckpreis="false">12.45</preis>
        <lieferant>Fa. Richard</lieferant>
    </artikel>
    <artikel id="3245">
        <name>Bananen</name>
        <preis stueckpreis="false">15.67</preis>
        <lieferant>Fa. Hoeller</lieferant>
    </artikel>
    <artikel id="6745">
        <name>Kohl</name>
        <preis stueckpreis="false">3.10</preis>
        <lieferant>Fa. Reinhardt</lieferant>
    </artikel>
    <artikel id="7789">
        <name>Ananas</name>
        <preis stueckpreis="true">8.60</preis>
        <lieferant>Fa. Richard</lieferant>
    </artikel>
</lieferungen>
```

I want to create the following output via xslt:

```
Fa. Helbig supplies: Kirschen

Fa. Liebig supplies: apfel

Fa. Krause supplies: apfel Kirschen

Fa. Mertes supplies: apfel

Fa. Hoeller supplies: Kirschen Kohl Bananen

Fa. Reinhardt supplies: Kohl

Fa. Richard supplies: Kirschen Ananas
```

To this end, I wrote the following xslt code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">


    <xsl:template match="lieferungen">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>
                    <xsl:text>Lieferanten</xsl:text>
                </title>
            </head>
            <body bgcolor="#ffffff">
                <h1>
                    <xsl:text>Suppliers</xsl:text>
                </h1>
                <hr/>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="//lieferant"></xsl:apply-templates>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="lieferant">
        <p>
            <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
            <xsl:text> supplies: </xsl:text>
            <xsl:for-each select="//artikel[lieferant/text() = current()/text()]">
                <xsl:value-of select="name/text()"/>
                <xsl:text></xsl:text>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </p>
    </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This gives me the following output:

```
Fa. Krause supplies: apfelKirschen
Fa. Helbig supplies: Kirschen
Fa. Liebig supplies: apfel
Fa. Krause supplies: apfelKirschen
Fa. Mertes supplies: apfel
Fa. Hoeller supplies: KirschenKohlBananen
Fa. Hoeller supplies: KirschenKohlBananen
Fa. Richard supplies: KirschenAnanas
Fa. Hoeller supplies: KirschenKohlBananen
Fa. Reinhardt supplies: Kohl
Fa. Richard supplies: KirschenAnanas
```

In order to get rid of the repetitions, I changed the xslt-code as follows (note the comments marking the two lines which were modified/added):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
        version="2.0">

         <!--THE FOLLOWING LINE OF CODE WAS ADDED (CHANGE 1/2): -->
         <xsl:key name="suppliers" match="lieferant" use="lieferant" />   
           <xsl:template match="lieferungen">
            <html>
                <head>
                    <title>
                        <xsl:text>Lieferanten</xsl:text>
                    </title>
                </head>
                <body bgcolor="#ffffff">
                    <h1>
                        <xsl:text>Suppliers</xsl:text>
                    </h1>
                    <hr/>

<!--THE FOLLOWING LINE OF CODE WAS MODIFIED (CHANGE 2/2):-->                        
<xsl:apply-templates select="//lieferant[generate-id()=generate-id(key('suppliers', lieferant)[1])]"></xsl:apply-templates>

                </body>
            </html>
        </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match="lieferant">
            <p>
                <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
                <xsl:text> supplies: </xsl:text>
                <xsl:for-each select="//artikel[lieferant/text() = current()/text()]">
                    <xsl:value-of select="name/text()"/>
                    <xsl:text></xsl:text>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </p>
        </xsl:template>


    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

However, this broke the code. What's wrong with the code I used?

Comment: If (as it seems) you're using XSLT 2.0, why are you trying to use Muenchian grouping? XSLT 2.0 has built-in methods for both grouping and for getting distinct values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output you want can be achieved quite simply by:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/lieferungen">
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Lieferanten</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>Suppliers</h1>
            <hr/>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="artikel" group-by="lieferant">
                <p>
                    <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/>
                    <xsl:text> supplies: </xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="current-group()/name"/>
                </p>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using an XSLT 2.0 processor like your stylesheet version indicates, see michael.hor257k's answer. Otherwise, here's what was wrong with your stylesheet...

In the two places that you changed the code the context was `lieferant`, but you were trying to use the value of a child `lieferant`. In your source, `lieferant` doesn't have a child `lieferant`.

For example, in your xsl:key, you select `lieferant` and also use `lieferant`. When you want to `use` the same node selected, use `.`.

It was the same thing in the use of `key()`; it was used inside of a predicate on `lieferant` so to use that context use `.`.

Here's your updated XSLT. I modified it at the same places you did, but also added a space inside the xsl:text to separate the `name`'s. I added a comment indicating this change to keep it consistent.

One other thing I did is change the version to 1.0 and remove the unused `xs` namespace declaration. (Doesn't really change anything in the output of this stylesheet.)

**Updated XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

  <!--THE FOLLOWING LINE OF CODE WAS ADDED (CHANGE 1/3): -->
  <xsl:key name="suppliers" match="lieferant" use="." />
  <xsl:template match="lieferungen">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>
          <xsl:text>Lieferanten</xsl:text>
        </title>
      </head>
      <body bgcolor="#ffffff">
        <h1>
          <xsl:text>Suppliers</xsl:text>
        </h1>
        <hr/>

        <!--THE FOLLOWING LINE OF CODE WAS MODIFIED (CHANGE 2/3):-->
        <xsl:apply-templates
          select="//lieferant[generate-id()=generate-id(key('suppliers', .)[1])]"/>

      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="lieferant">
    <p>
      <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
      <xsl:text> supplies: </xsl:text>
      <xsl:for-each select="//artikel[lieferant/text() = current()/text()]">
        <xsl:value-of select="name/text()"/>
        <!--THE FOLLOWING LINE OF CODE WAS MODIFIED (CHANGE 3/3):-->
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </p>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

**UPDATE**

Like Michael mentioned in a comment, you're losing half of the benefits of Muenchian grouping with `<xsl:for-each select="//artikel[lieferant/text() = current()/text()]">`.

I would suggest creating a key that selects at the `artikel` level and uses `lieferant` as the key.

Example (with comments to indicate all changes)...

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

  <!--THE FOLLOWING LINE OF CODE WAS ADDED (CHANGE 1/7): -->
  <xsl:key name="suppliers" match="artikel" use="lieferant" />
  <xsl:template match="lieferungen">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>
          <xsl:text>Lieferanten</xsl:text>
        </title>
      </head>
      <body bgcolor="#ffffff">
        <h1>
          <xsl:text>Suppliers</xsl:text>
        </h1>
        <hr/>

        <!--THE FOLLOWING LINE OF CODE WAS MODIFIED (CHANGE 2/7):-->
        <xsl:apply-templates
          select="//artikel[generate-id()=generate-id(key('suppliers', lieferant)[1])]"/>

      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
  <!--THE FOLLOWING LINE OF CODE WAS MODIFIED (CHANGE 3/7):-->
  <xsl:template match="artikel">
    <p>
      <!--THE FOLLOWING LINE OF CODE WAS MODIFIED (CHANGE 4/7):-->
      <xsl:value-of select="lieferant"/>
      <xsl:text> supplies: </xsl:text>
      <!--THE FOLLOWING LINE OF CODE WAS MODIFIED (CHANGE 5/7):-->
      <xsl:for-each select="key('suppliers',lieferant)">
        <!--THE FOLLOWING LINE OF CODE WAS MODIFIED (CHANGE 6/7):-->
        <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
        <!--THE FOLLOWING LINE OF CODE WAS MODIFIED (CHANGE 7/7):-->
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </p>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However, you could just modify the xsl:for-each:

```
<xsl:for-each select="key('suppliers',.)">
  <xsl:value-of select="../name"/>
  <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: `<xsl:for-each select="//artikel[lieferant/text() = current()/text()]">` You are losing half of the benefits of Muenchian grouping by not reusing the key here.

Comment: @michael.hor257k - Yes that's true. I'll change that too and add a note for the OP.